# Rotate image on its Y-axis and show different div

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, rotation

I have a form that includes a button (on the left). On the right I have a picture. So when the user clicks the button, I want the picture to have a return around effect and show another div that displays the result. So here is my code:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 calculate__content">
              <form>
                <div class="calorie__button__area">
                  <button
                    type="submit"
                    class="button-secondary button__calculate"
                  >
                    BUTTON
                  </button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 calculate__content">
              <img
                  src="./assets/img/calculate.png"
                  alt="Weight Calculation Image"
                />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 calculate__content__result">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 calculate__content">
                  <div class="result__box">
                    <div class="title">RESULT:</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12"></div>
              </div>
            </div>


.calculate__content__result {
display: none;
}
```

So at first, calculate__content__result is not displaying. But when the user clicks the button, the image rotates on its Y-axis with the css effect and calculate__content__result should be shown instead of image. I am also really struggling with rotating its Y-axis with the css animation effect.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

html need some changes:

- add `<img>` tag inside the result__box.
- you should change button type to "button" otherwise the page will refresh every time you click on it.
- add a unique class name for the  tag that contains the first picture.
- add onclick attribute to the button and assign "rotate()" to it.

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 calculate__content">
    <form>
      <div class="calorie__button__area">
        <button
        onclick="rotate()"
          type="button"
          class="button-secondary button__calculate"
        >
          BUTTON
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 calculate__content first_image">
    <img
        src="./assets/img/calculate.png"
        alt="Weight Calculation Image"
      />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 calculate__content__result">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 calculate__content">
        <div class="result__box">
          <div class="title">RESULT:</div>
          <img
            class = "result_image"
            src="./assets/img/calculate.png"
            alt="Weight Calculation Image"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

your initial style should be something like this:

```
<style>
        .calculate__content__result{
            display: none;
        }
        .result_image{
            animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
        }
        @keyframes rotation {
            from {
                transform: rotateY(0deg);
            }
            to {
                transform: rotateY(359deg);
            }
        }
    </style>
```

and add this script after `</body>` tag:

```
<script>
    function rotate() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("first_image")[0].style.display = "none";
        document.getElementsByClassName("calculate__content__result")[0].style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
```